# Relative path doesn't seem to work with Powershell include and PSScriptRoot

Tags: powershell

I tried to use ".." in Powershell for including parent relative path

```
. "$PSScriptRoot\..\test.ps1"
```

It doesn't seem to work at least with paths which have spaces. Is there any syntax that could work ?

Comment: What PowerShell version? Are you running that line from a script or directly from the PowerShell console?

Comment: Unable to repro this behavior, works fine with paths that contains spaces

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers on Powershell for Windows 7 I guess it's 3 (I'm not at work I can't check for now)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen weird but thanks, will try again, maybe it's because I have nested inclusion.

Comment: `$PSScriptRoot` is always the path of the folder containing the script being executed as long as the code being executed executed originates and is loaded from a file. It doesn't matter if the file is a script file, or a function, or a cmdlet, or a .psm1.

Comment: Windows 7 ships with PowerShell v2, please check the output of `$PSVersionTable`. And again, from where are you running that statement?